# How does one use the auxiliary verbs, went and gone

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I hear people say, I had/have went as in, ‘I had went to the movies the other night. Shouldn’t it be either I had gone or I went?

Answer (score 1):

It's always *I have/had gone*.

*Have/had* is the auxillary verb; and what follows that is supposed to be the past participle.  *Go* has an irregular past participle of *gone*.

*Went* is the irregular past tense of *go*.

Regular English verbs have the same form of past and past participle, but not *go*.

Uneducated speakers might say *I had went* - you don't want to do this where you are expected to sound educated.

Comment: I think you mean "some people who speak a non-standard variety of English".